# Why does negating a static member variable produce a linker error?

Tags: c++

Please consider the following mini example

```
// CFoo.hpp
class CFoo{
private:
    static const double VPI = 0.5;    
public:
    double getVpi();
};

// CFoo.cpp
#include "CFoo.hpp"    
double CFoo::getVpi(){
    double x = -VPI;
    return x;
}

// main.cpp
#include "CFoo.hpp"    
int main(){
    CFoo aFoo();
    return 0;
}
```

Lining the program with gcc version 4.5.1 produces the error `CFoo.cpp: undefined reference to CFoo::VPI`. The error dose **not** occur if

- VPI is not negated
- the negation is written as `double x = -1 * VPI;`
- Declaration and definition of class CFoo happen in the same file

Do you know the reason for this error?

Comment: This is not valid C++. You cannot initialize non-integral, non-constexpr static class members inline. Make sure you enable and heed all your compiler warnings and compliance features.

Comment: @KerrekSB care to explain why this is not valid ?

Comment: Compiling with clang gives: `warning: in-class initializer for static data member of type 'const double' is a GNU extension`

Comment: @undu - `static` members must be defined and initialized outside the class.

Comment: @undu: I've given you tips how to discover what's wrong; consider it your Sherlock Monday activity :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I know why this is not valid, but this is a question and answer site, so why not give the answer to OP question if you know it ?

Comment: @undu: Because that comment, and its adherent problems, aren't the actual topic of the OP's question. The code is wrong and broken, whence my comment, but the answer to the question is a different one.

Comment: @KirilKirov static const integral members can be initialised within a class. A double cannot.

Comment: @KerrekSB Fair enough. My Bad.

Comment: @user93353: And in C++11, arbitrary `static constexpr` class members can also be initialized inline. But they have to be `constexpr` (and so does the initializer, I believe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.  Primarily, this is not valid C++03:

```
class CFoo{
private:
    static const double VPI = 0.5;    
// ...
};
```

The declaration of a static data member can specify a constant initializer if and only if that initializer is `const` integral or `const` enumeration type.  `0.5` is neither of these, and hence your code is not valid C++.  **9.4.2 Static data members** covers this:

> 2/ The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is
>   not a definition [...]The definition for a static data member shall
>   appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.
>   [...]
>
> 4/ If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration
>   type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a
>   constant-initializer which shall be an integral constant expression
>   (5.19).

In order to initialize `VPI`, you must do so in the CPP file:

### header:

```
class CFoo{
private:
    static const double VPI;    
};
```

### cpp :

```
const double CFoo::VPI = 0.5;
```

Another problem, unrelated, is here:

```
int main(){
    CFoo aFoo(); // NOT OK
    return 0;
```

The expression `CFoo aFoo();` doesn't do what you think it does.  You think it declares an object `aFoo` of type `CFoo` and initializes it using `CFoo`'s default constructor.  But what it actually does is declare a function named `aFoo` taking no parameters, returning a `CFoo` by value.  This is known as the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).  In order to do what you want, simple omit the parenthesis:

```
CFoo aFoo;
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and helpful answer. I still don't understand why the linker behaves like that but my original problem is solved.

Comment: Deve:  One can never know what will happen in the mysterious world of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Deve: The compiler accepted (failed to diagnose, probably due to partial support of C++11) the initializer in the declaration, but that still leaves the member undefined. When you negate a variable that is *not* a constant expression (and `double`s cannot be constant expressions) that is a *use* (*odr-use* in C++11) of the variable and the linker requires the definition, which makes it complain as you did not provide one.